# VBA: Referencing a Range stored as variable in a Sorting sub

Tags: vba, excel

Very novice programmer so hope my question isn't too dumb. I'm trying to set make a common sorting subroutine that I can call, but where the sorting subroutine looks at a variable for the range. This way I can set the range elsewhere (such as the button where I call the subroutine) and not have it hard-coded into the sorting routine.

So far my train of thought is this:

```
Dim Column As Range
Sub SortCodeDsc()
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Benchmark Data").Sort.SortFields.Clear
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Benchmark Data").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A4:A100").Value, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Benchmark Data").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A4:HH100")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Year_Click()
    Set Column = ActiveSheet.Range("A4:A100")
    Call SortCodeDsc
End Sub
```

So where `Range("A4:A100")` is in the Sub `SortCodeDsc` I would instead like to call variable Column which I Set to the range from `A4` to `A100`. How do I properly call that variable when calling the subroutine?

Comment: `Private` or `Public Column As Range`  then use `column`  http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/vb6-variable-scope

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not a good idea to use the word "Column" as a variable.  That should be a saved word.  Use Column1 instead and turn your sub into a function, passing it the range parameter.

```
Function SortCodeDsc(columnRange As Range)
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Benchmark Data").Sort.SortFields.Clear
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Benchmark Data").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=columnRange, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Benchmark Data").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A4:HH100")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
    End With
End Function

Private Sub Year_Click()
Dim column1 As Range

Set column1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Benchmark Data").Range("A1:A100")
    Run SortCodeDsc(column1)
End Sub
```

Comment: You could also pass it the worksheet to generalize the function for different applications.  like